# Stop vim from folding git commit

Tags: vim, git-commit, folding

Vim automatically folds my code when I open a new file. How can I stop it from folding the text when I run `git commit -a`, since I don't want folding only in this specific case?

I currently have this line in my code `setlocal foldmethod=syntax` to fold all code automatically.

I tried to add this line before and after setting the foldmethod `autocmd FileType gitcommit setlocal nofoldenable`, but it did not changing anything.

Comment: @romainl I would not ask here if I would know how to do that.

Answer (score 4):

Put this into `after/ftplugin/gitcommit.vim` in your runtime (`~/.vim`) or a plugin:

```
setlocal nofoldenable
```

Alternately, in your `.vimrc`,

```
autocmd FileType gitcommit setlocal nofoldenable
```

Comment: I tried placing the `autocmd` command before and after `setlocal foldmethod=syntax`, but it did not change the behaviour

Comment: Do you mean you want to disable folding for any file you edit? If so, try instead: `autocmd FileType gitcommit set nofoldenable`

Comment: @yolenoyer Sorry, I should have be more clear, I added `autocmd FileType gitcommit setlocal nofoldenable` before and after `setlocal foldmethod=syntax`, just what you wrote

Comment: Regarding your added explanation, where do you have `setlocal foldmethod=syntax`? If it's in `.vimrc`, it probably does not do what you want. Also, can you run `:verbose set foldenable? foldmethod?` while in gitcommit state and report what it says?